# column reference is ambiguous but i dont have the column in my query

Tags: postgresql, go, sql-update

So Im trying to make an upsert in Go for Postgres. I dynamically make my query and it comes to:

```
INSERT INTO v2.products (id,company_id,name) 
VALUES (1,2,'foo5') 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO 
UPDATE 
   SET id = EXCLUDED.id, 
       company_id = EXCLUDED.company_id, 
       name = EXCLUDED.name
```

When I call db.Query with this I get an error saying:

```
pq: column reference "id" is ambiguous
```

I have tried adding the table name to the id in the ON CONFLICT ("v2.products.id") but it tells me the column doesnt exist.

When I run the same query (with just id in the ON CONFLICT braces) in Postgres it works fine

Comment: Why do you need to set `id` if that's the column with the conflict? Isn't it already correct?

Comment: Setting `id` is pretty useless. But nevertheless: it [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c99e595da521d76e09c29fcf18f93c0a)

Comment: First time implementing an upsert. I'll sort this out in my logic for generating the query tomorrow. And it works fine for me in Postgres too, it just doesn't work from go

Comment: [This](https://go.dev/play/p/eOgkf5hwaPt) worked fine for me (Postgres 14.3, Go 1.18.3 pq 1.10.4 - obviously it will not run in the playground). Note that the [pq readme](https://github.com/lib/pq) suggests moving to [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx).

Comment: As I understand, you should use db.Exec